# Syntax is incorrect. CI configuration validated, including all configuration added with the include keyword

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I simulated my project on gitlab,

Status:
Syntax is correct. CI configuration validated, including all configuration added with the include keyword.

I run Pipeline cannot be run.
Included file `http://gitlab...com.tr/iot/IoTFrontend/-/blob/main/Desktop/skywaveiotui_devops/.gitlab-ci.yml` does not have valid YAML syntax!

Can you help me ?

I changed my path I couldnt be solved

Answer (score 0):

Check if file you want to include is valid using [ci-lint](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/lint.html). If this doesn't help try including file using relative paths. For example:

```yaml
include:
  - project: iot/IoTFrontend
    file: /Desktop/skywaveiotui_devops/.gitlab-ci.yml
```

Also you need at least reporter role in the repo which contains file to include. For more information see gitlab-ci [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#include)

Answer (score 0):

GitLab expects the response from that link to ONLY contain the YAML file. However, the link you used is an HTML response, not a YAML file.

Use the `/-/raw/` path instead of `/-/blob/`

See for example the difference between these links:

- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/raw/master/.gitlab-ci.yml
- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml

So you want to use:

```
http://gitlab...com.tr/iot/IoTFrontend/-/raw/main/Desktop/skywaveiotui_devops/.gitlab-ci.yml
```

Alternatively, use a different include format, as suggested in another answer.

Comment: I got message "Pipeline cannot be run. No stages / jobs for this pipeline." when I use http://gitlab...com.tr/iot/IoTFrontend/-/raw/main/Desktop/skywaveiotui_devops/.gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: @SemraKonancı that's an unrelated issue, but indicates the include issue was fixed. Now you have another problem. In order to fix that, we'd need to know the contents of the files... as a hint, check any `rules:` you have to make sure jobs will actually run. If you can't figure it out after doing some research, consider raising a separate question.